# How do you fulfill Steven Seer's upperclassman goal?

Tags: wizard-school

Steven Seer's upperclassman goal reads "You are affected by 'double symbols' 3 times on your turn."  It is not clear to me what 'double symbols' are thus not clear how to fulfill this goal.  Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

There is speculation on https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1705755/rules-problemsclarifications that the 'double symbols' refer to the card backs of the school deck, which is also what I assumed.  However, that entire thread seems to be people asking and answering their own questions and I am hoping for a more official source (or at least some people voting this way).

If you have the same answer but a better source, I am happy to delete this answer and give you answer credit.